# How to debug data saving of form after click submit button in angular JS

Tags: angularjs, yii

I am new in angular JS, working with existing project on angular 1.2.16

please check the code sample

```
<form role="form" name="UserCreateForm"
    novalidate class="biocheck-form">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4"> <input class="input-forms" placeholder="Usuario" aa-field-group="UserCreate.data.username" type="text" aa-label="Usuario"
                required maxlength="20"> </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4"> <input class="input-forms" placeholder="ejemplo@mail.com" aa-field-group="UserCreate.data.email" type="email"
                aa-label="Email" required> </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4"> <input class="input-forms" placeholder="" aa-field-group="UserCreate.data.newPassword" type="password" aa-label="Contraseña"
                required> </div>
    </div>
```

Rol

```
    </div> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" aa-submit-form="UserCreate.on.doUserCreate()"> Guardar </button>        <button class="btn btn-cancel pull-right" ng-click="UserCreate.on.toUserList()"> Cancelar </button> </form>
```

I want to check debug the next flow of the code. If anything is unclear please comment.
I want to check how it is save the data in DB this project used yii for handling server side request.
Thanks

Comment: Que exactmente es la pregunta? it isn't clear what you're asking for.

Comment: i want to identify which function or controller called after submit button ?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you need to open the developer tools in your browser, go to the Source tab and find the js file that holds the function on your ng-click. Then put a breakpoint there and click the button. The browser should stop in the breakpoint and with F10 you can go line by line to your code.

Comment: Where I can put the break point. How can i identify that which function called after submit button ?

Comment: When you click the button the `UserCreate.on.doUserCreate()` function must run. The function exists in a js file in your directory structure (You must know in which file exists). [Here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints) you can see how you can place a breakpoint on chrome and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger_(before_Firefox_52)/How_to/Set_a_breakpoint) on firefox. I hope this helps